# Error with psycopg2 when execute runserver with DJANGO

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, psycopg2

I've been all morning trying to start my django project and it seems impossible,
everytime I try to start it i get the next error:

```
(venv) djimenez@TADEL-INF:/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl$ python bullfrogloader/manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f04b7d7b6a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/djimenez/Desktop/bfl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

I know that is something about the database but I'm unable to find the mistake.

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==2.1.0
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==18.2.0
backcall==0.1.0
bcrypt==3.1.6
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.5
decorator==4.3.2
Django==2.1.3
django-common-helpers==0.9.2
django-cron==0.5.1
django-mathfilters==0.4.0
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.5
djangorestframework==3.9.1
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
fabric==2.4.0
idna==2.9
invoke==1.2.0
ipython==7.2.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.3.4
jedi==0.13.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mock==2.0.0
more-itertools==5.0.0
mysqlclient==1.4.6
paramiko==2.4.2
parso==0.3.2
pbr==5.1.2
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pluggy==0.8.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.8
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.7.0
pyasn1==0.4.5
pycparser==2.19
Pygments==2.3.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pytest==3.10.1
pytz==2018.9
requests==2.23.0
six==1.12.0
traitlets==4.3.2
typed-ast==1.4.1
urllib3==1.25.8
wcwidth==0.1.7
wrapt==1.11.1
```

I have tried everything but i'm unable to fix it.
I'm using virtualenv with python 3.6

Does anyone have a clue of what is happening here?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you able to log in to the database using `psql` from the command line, using the credentials in your `DATABASES` setting in django?

Comment: yep, database is working correctly

Comment: I think I would try setting a breakpoint in `psycopg2/__init__.py` line 126 and see if you can get any more details out of that `OperationalError` about what's causing it.

Comment: that's a good idea, ill try, thank you